# Blender only shows blank image when rendered

Tags: eevee-render-engine

[image][image]Can anyone help me. I tried rendering my animation in blender 2.9 but apparently, it only shows a black image. Even in the render option, it only shows an empty image. I think I messed up something in its settings. Hope anyone can help me, I'm just new to blender so please bear with me. I'll upload the .blend file, hope anyone can look at it. Thank you.

https://ibb.co/JRV0zz6

Comment: Screenshots, please! This is terribly general unless you have images to show us what you mean.

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard here is my link file can you look at it? [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=9eRSJnDZ" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/9eRSJnDZ/)

Comment: alright, I’ve downloaded it, but now you are waiting for things in my life. If you add screenshots to the question we can help you faster. Stackexchange allows you to embed them directly.

Comment: I've already added it. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: …and a shot of the Rendering screen?

Comment: already updated at the top

Comment: Many duplicates of this question end up being solved in that an object hidden in the viewport is not hidden in render and obscures the camera and or lighting.   https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=render+is+blank

Comment: ok, much better. @batFINGER that is not the case here, unless it’s the camera.

Comment: I don't think it's the camera either

Comment: Your World is set to Glass BSDF... Use a Background Shader instead.

Comment: @batFINGER: you were right.

Comment: @Gorgious: you were partially right ;)

Comment: Thanks, @Gorgious!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you tap the right most button here:

[image]

you can check how the rendered image would look like.

There you can also see the black screen.

Then tap on the two button right to your cube001: (eye + camera)

[image]

Then add a sun : strength : 50

and you will get:

[image]

[image]

hint: without any light in the scene (whatever "form" of light) you won't see anything (which results in black screen)

instead of adding a sun you could also change the world shader to a background shader as @Gorgious said.

Comment: Oh my goodness!!!! It worked!!! Thank you so much y'all!!! I tried changing my world properties from glass BSDF to Background surface, and it worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: you are welcome. would be nice if you could check the checkmark left to my answer. thank you.

Comment: Already did ma friend. Thank you so much for the effort, I don't know that I should put light scenes in my scenes.  Appreciate your effort, thanks!

Comment: thank you!!!!!! no problem, we all started some time ago and didn't know anything about blender...but some people seem to forget this here very quickly :(

Comment: hope you could help more people in the future. Thank you!